# SELECT 2 different data sets using MYSQL IF

Tags: mysql, if-statement

Essentially what I want to do is make a selection on data displayed based upon a users status when logged in, for example if the user is a trial user then select data from a specific date range but if they are a paid user then select a greater date range. I have tried the following code below but it throws up an error saying my syntax is incorrect. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
IF (SELECT MemberStatus FROM user WHERE Memberstatus = 'Trial') 
THEN
  SELECT *
  FROM article
  WHERE date > '1990/01/01';  
ELSE
  SELECT *
  FROM article
  WHERE date > '2000/01/01';
ENDIF;
```

Comment: Is your example logic the wrong way around (you seem to be saying that trial users get > '1990/01/01' and paid users get > '2000/01/01')?

Comment: Also, presumably, the `SELECT MemberStatus...` part of the query should be referencing a username (value/parameter) - unless your logic is meant to be about all users in the user table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's wrong to do this (check user status and select items depending on it) in one query. You'll probably need to use trial restrictions or display trial status somewhere else in your code. So better to store it in instance of user's profile or a varialble and build queries regarding user's status.

Comment: Yeah, like... Do the checkings on your server-scripts, then take a corresponding query to get the data you need. Much simpler and cleaner, more dynamic as well.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need an IF. This is also standard SQL

```
  SELECT *
  FROM article
  WHERE date >
           CASE
                 WHEN EXISTS (SELECT * FROM user WHERE Memberstatus = 'Trial')
                            THEN '2000/01/01'
                 ELSE '1990/01/01'
           END;
```

Edit: as per comment to question, the SELECT from user is probably incomplete

Comment: @Shaun: And you probably need to change the user check to something like `WHERE Memberstatus = 'Trial' and userid = @userX`

Comment: That looks like it could potentially work, what about if I needed to display two different select statements based upon the same criteria. For example:
Select a link if they are a user and select just the title if they are a trial user. Essentially restricting what is displayed based upon their user status?

Comment: @Shaun: that would be two queries then. Use `IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM user WHERE Memberstatus = 'Trial')...` in this case